# Cassandra : Key Level access in Map type columns

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

In Cassandra,Suppose we require to access key level against map type column. how to do it?

Create statement:

```
create table collection_tab2(
   empid int,
   emploc map<text,text>,
   primary key(empid));
```

Insert statement:

```
 insert into collection_tab2 (empid, emploc ) VALUES ( 100,{'CHE':'Tata Consultancy Services','CBE':'CTS','USA':'Genpact LLC'} );
```

select:

```
select emploc from collection_tab2;
empid | emploc
------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  100 | {'CBE': 'CTS', 'CHE': 'Tata Consultancy Services', 'USA': 'Genpact LLC'}
```

In that case, if want to access 'USA' key alone . What I should do?

I tried based on the Index. But all values are coming.

```
CREATE INDEX fetch_index ON killrvideo.collection_tab2 (keys(emploc));

select * from collection_tab2 where emploc CONTAINS KEY 'CBE';

empid | emploc
------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  100 | {'CBE': 'CTS', 'CHE': 'Tata Consultancy Services', 'USA': 'Genpact LLC'}
```

But expected:

```
'CHE': 'Tata Consultancy Services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a data model change I would strongly recommend:

```
create table collection_tab2(
   empid int,
   emploc_key text,
   emploc_value text,
   primary key(empid, emploc_key));
```

Then you can query and page through simply as the emploc_key is clustering key instead of part of the cql collection that has multiple limits and negative performance impacts.

Then:

```
insert into collection_tab2 (empid, emploc_key, emploc_value) VALUES ( 100, 'CHE', 'Tata Consultancy Services');
insert into collection_tab2 (empid, emploc_key, emploc_value) VALUES ( 100, 'CBE, 'CTS');
insert into collection_tab2 (empid, emploc_key, emploc_value) VALUES ( 100, 'USA', 'Genpact LLC');
```

Can also put it in a ***unlogged*** batch and it will still be applied efficiently and atomically because all in the same partition.

To do it as you have you can after 4.0 with [CASSANDRA-7396](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7396) with `[]` selectors like:

```
SELECT emploc['USA'] FROM collection_tab2 WHERE empid = 100;
```

But I would still strongly recommend data model changes as its significantly more efficient, and can work in existing versions with:

```
SELECT * FROM collection_tab2 WHERE empid = 100 AND emploc_key = 'USA';
```